# Can I set up a route that MVC will go to if no other routes match?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's a portion of my route config:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ApiControllerActionAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: null, //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } //,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Account",
            url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "spa",
            "{section}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { section = @"home|questions|admin" });
```

The "spa" route is the very last route in the list.

Is there a way that I can change the last route called spa such that **everything** that does not match the routes before this goes to the controller Home and the action Index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
"spa",
"{*path}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```